# Diffusion into PMMA

Tags: acid-base, plastics, hydrolysis

My thesis is about effect of cigarette smoke to PMMA polymer, apparently cigarette smoke have some amount of eugenol which is mildly acidic and they will evaporate when the cigarette is burned.

In the normal situation PMMA is subject to constant hydrolysis but the reaction is very slow, when there is an acid present the acid become a catalyst for hydrolysis reaction.

my hypothesis is the PMMA will be weakened because it absorbs some water from humidity and when there is eugenol vapor in air , Eugenol will diffusing to the water in PMMA polymer. now I need to know how to calculate how much eugenol concentration present in water inside the polymer.

Comment: I have found that my specimen at least contain 14722.5 µg water.

Comment: "concentration present in water inside the polymer"? Your polymer is solvent not water

Comment: @Mithoron I dont understand , why my solvent would be the polymer not the water inside the polymer ?

Comment: In a solution, the solvent is the component present in the highest amount. Not all solvents are liquids.

Comment: @BenNorris now I get it :D , but if the eugenol is dissolved in PMMA polymer rather in water inside the polymer how could it make it the environment acidic ? isn't acid only present in the form of Aqueous ?